# VBA - struggling to calc and write StDev data into an array with a For Next loop

Tags: arrays, vba, for-loop, offset

11/24/14 - as per below.....

Still trying to figure this out - might it be easier by creating a smaller array which could roll through the larger array? ...then any necessary calcs could be done on the entirety of the small array.

I cannot figure out how to isolate just a (rolling) subset of an array. The rolling subset could be used for moving averages, standard devs, max/min, etc.

---

11/21/14 - I have made several attempts, this is the latest iteration. It shouldn't produce meaningful output until the minimum periods have been looped thru (`stdev_periods = 10`).

--`pct_chg_array()` is an array which holds percent change data from `i=2 to i = 2541`... declared as variant

--`stdev_periods = 10` ...declared as integer

--`i` is a counter ...declared as integer

--`stdev_array()` is an empty array which I hope to populate with a standard deviation calculation for a rolling n period range ...declared as variant

--`Option Base 1` and `Option Explicit` are on

```
For i = 2 To 2541
    If IsNumeric(i) And i <> 0 Then
        stdev_array(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.stdev(Range(pct_chg_array(i, 1).Offset(-stdev_periods, 0), pct_chg_array(i, 0)))
    Else
        stdev_array(i, 1) = 0
    End If
Next i
```

Any guidance would be immensely appreciated. Thanks!

----EDIT----

Just to simplify, this is how I would express it in a worksheet formula...

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(OFFSET($E3,-stdev_periods+1,0)),STDEV(OFFSET($E3,0,0,-stdev_periods)),0)
```

...with `"stdev_periods" = 10` and column E holding 1 period %chg data (`ie =$E3/$E2-1`).

Comment: Do you think you could change your variable names to reflect the role they play in the Standard Deviation formula? That might help us. Thanks.

Comment: good suggestion - hopefully it reads easier now. ty.

Comment: bigger picture - i am trying to analyze price time series data for stocks, and was advised to collect and manipulate data in a 3D array. i am a complete novice with VBA so i am just trying to take it one piece at a time. thx again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this function in the module:

```
Public Function Slice(vntInputArray As Variant, lngStartIndex As Long, lngEndIndex As Long)   
    'Use to return an arbitrary-sized subset from a 1 dimensional array.
    'Assumes developer is using Option Base 1

    Dim vntSubArray() As Variant, lngInputIndex As Long
    Dim lngElementCountIndex As Long: lngElementCountIndex = 1


    For lngInputIndex = lngStartIndex To lngEndIndex
        ReDim Preserve vntSubArray(lngInputIndex)
        vntSubArray(lngElementCountIndex) = vntInputArray(lngInputIndex)
        lngElementCountIndex = (lngElementCountIndex + 1)
    Next lngInputIndex

    Slice = vntSubArray

End Function
```

Adding the function to your code:

```
For i = 2 To 2541
    If IsNumeric(i) And i > stdev_periods Then     'Using greater than to account for Option Base 1
        stdev_array(i, 1) = WorksheetFunction.stdev(Slice( pct_chg_array, (i -stdev_periods), i))
    Else
        stdev_array(i, 1) = 0
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: The problem I keep running into is I have had a hard time isolating just a small subset of data within an array. For example, if i have 100 data points in a single dimension array ("price_array"), I cannot figure out how to get the max, min or average for just 10 at a time. this doesn't seem to work: application.max(range(price_array(1),price_array(10)))
I think that just gives me the max of the values of those 2 coordinates - not the max of all the values between those 2. Is that incorrect?

Comment: Thanks for explaining.  The problem is that, as far as I know, there isn't a convenient way to "slice" an arbitrary subset of an array using VBA.  I've added a function to the answer that I think will resolve the issue.